# bash create for loop with an array variable

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

i am trying to make output of a command be read by a for loop, but in such a way that the loop variable would be an array. is that possible?
this is what I've been trying so far:

```
function samplevals() {
    echo '"aa bb"'
    echo '"cc dd"'
    echo '"ee ff" "gg hh"'
}

samplevar='"aa bb"
"cc dd"
"ee ff" "gg hh"'

echo call function samplevals:
for x in `samplevals `; do echo ">$x<"; done

echo read variable samplevar:
echo $samplevar
for x in $samplevar; do echo ">$x<"; done

echo process output of 'echo samplevar:'
for x in `echo $samplevar`; do echo ">$x<"; done

echo "the thing with set"
for x in $samplevar; do set -- $x ; echo "\$1=>$1<,\$2=>$2<"; done
```

but the output is always the same:

```
>"aa<
>bb"<
>"cc<
>dd"<
>"ee<
>ff"<
>"gg<
>hh"<
```

Can I somehow prevent bash from splitting the elements into smaller pieces?

Comment: The quotes are literal data, not syntactic quotes. You don't have any arrays in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The way to define an array in `bash` is

```
samplevars=("aa bb" "cc dd" "ee ff" "gg hh")
for x in "${samplevars[@]}"; do
    echo ">$x<"
done
```

Comment: There *is* no simple way to create an array from command output, because there is no such thing as an array *value* in `bash`, only array *parameters* whose syntax gives the appearance of array values. An array is really closer to a loosely related set of individual variables, tied together with some syntactic sugar.

Comment: This almost works.  Change samplevars to samplevar on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592181/5291015), using `read` command. The `-a` flag part of the command lets the output to written out to an array.

```
IFS=$'\t' read -ra arrayDef < <(echo -ne '"abc def"\t"ghi jkl"')
for x in "${arrayDef[@]}"; do
    echo ">$x<"
done
```

You can replace the `echo` part with some command that generates such a string. Remember to update the `IFS` appropriately as to how the string is de-limited. In my case, I just a have the string de-limited by `\t`

Comment: This just shifts the "delimiter" from arbitrary whitespace to a tab specifically. It doesn't solve the underlying problem of having a separator that is *guaranteed* not to occur in an element of the array.

Comment: @chepner: Initially provided this as alternative complementing logic on seeing yours, but on seeing OP not approving of yours. Do you want me to delete it